# use of sub query in sum aggregate function

Tags: sql

The following query

```
select OrderID,fltprc
 from tab1
```

Gives me following result:

OrderID#       fltprc
1595           101.85
1585           25.00
1585           25.00 
1682           200.54

And I want sum of fltprc based on unique id

it means sum of fltprc of unique order.

Comment: @ypercube "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'" i think it is ms sql server.

Comment: @Hamlet you are right. The syntax is not correct in any DBMS but the error is from SQL-Server, most likely. The lack of `;` between statements suggests the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(DISTINCT fltprc) FROM tab1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect!

To store a value on a variable use:

```
SET @test := (select sum(distinct fltprc) from tab1);
SELECT @test;
```

take a look on this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4bbd1/13

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully follow your question.  If you are trying to get a sum of "fltprc" for each unique orderID then simply use a GROUP BY e.g.

```
SELECT
   OrderID,
   SUM(fltprc) 
FROM
   tab1
GROUP BY
   OrderID
```